# Git Error pushing

Tags: git

I've created a file in a branch, merge it to master OK, But I have an error pushing:

**>git push origin master**

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://nunito@tdk.com/
stash/scm/tdk-apps/tdk-admin-app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
```

This is the **>git status**:

```
# On branch development
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This is the **>git pull**

```
Password for 'https://nunito@tdk.com/':
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: did you pull before trying to push?

Comment: yes, git also suggest it to you.. look above: hint: (e.g 'git pull')

Comment: You are working on another branch! (development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your changes are not in sync with the remote repository.

```
git pull
```

If there are any conflicts you will need to resolve them. Otherwise you will be able to push.

You can also overwrite a remote branch if you are sure that the remote changes are not changes you wish to keep.

```
git push origin +development
```

In this case the "+" forces an override.

I would not recommend forcing an update when working in a team environment however as you would potentially be deleting other developers changes.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you are working on branch 'development' - Try to pull before push. Also suggested in hint:

```
git pull origin development
```

then:

```
git push origin development
```